# npm install express is not workimg

Tags: node.js, npm

It shows:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: which node version are you using?

Comment: Looks like your NPM installation is broken.

Comment: Probably this will help you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323982/error-cannot-find-module-lib-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: after reinstaling and  put this comment it started to work

Comment: nice :D cool !!!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue is due to the wrong path of node in system variable

update as `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: I put the path correctly but didn't work

Comment: If you're working with vs-code, do not forget to close every instance after having changed the path ;)